# Where does the "compound" DEP come from?

Tags: spacy

In the following SpaCy code:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("It was yesterday morning.")
doc[2].dep_
# 'compound'
doc[2].dep
# 7037928807040764755
doc[3].dep_
# 'npadmod'
doc[3].dep
# 428
```

I can track `npadmod` back to `symbols.pxd`enum.
But, where is '`compound`' defined (both string and ID) ?

[SOLVED]
Some DEPs come from the `symbols` enum, some are dynamically added by the language itself. The value is then the hash of the string name, and they are contained into a `StringStore`.

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("It was yesterday morning.")
doc[2].dep_
# 'compound'
doc[2].dep
# 7037928807040764755
nlp.vocab.strings[doc[2].dep]
# 'compound'
nlp.vocab.strings['compound']
# 7037928807040764755
```